# Display ggplot inside a DT Shiny Table Tooltip

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, datatables

I am trying to display a plot inside a tooltip. I only want the tooltip to display when I am hovering above the mpg row.  I was trying to achieve something like this: https://laustep.github.io/stlahblog/posts/DTqTips.html, but was coming up short. Below is a reprex solution with the plot I want to display.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(tidyverse)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    selectInput('cylSelect', choices = c(4,6,8), label ="Select the # of cylinders"),
    dataTableOutput('table'),
  ),
  
  server = function(server, input, output) {
    
    cars <- reactive({
      mtcars %>%
        filter(cyl == input$cylSelect) %>%
        group_by(am) %>%
        summarise(across(everything(), mean))
    })
    
    p <- renderPlot({ 
      cars() %>%
      ggplot(aes(x = am, y=mpg)) +
      geom_bar(stat = 'identity')
    })
    
    output$table <- renderDataTable({
      datatable(cars()

      )
    })
  }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but one option would be to use the [tippy](https://tippy.john-coene.com/index.html) package to create your column header.

```
library(shiny)
library(tippy)


tippy("Example Text", 
      tooltip = paste(img(src="http://tippy.john-coene.com/logo.png")),
      allowHTML = TRUE,
      placement = "bottom",
      theme = "light"
)
```

Afaik it only works with static images though, but you could simply save the output plot and reference it in the tooltip.